# Python: Print output on multiple Excel sheets

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I have 4 lists each having 33 values each and wish to print the combination in excel. Excel limits the number of rows in each sheet to **1,048,576** and the number of combinations exceeds the sheet limit by **137,345 values**.

**How should I continue printing the result in next sheet in the same workbook?**

```
a = [100, 101, 102,...,133]
b = [250, 251, 252,...,283]
c = [300, 301, 302,...,333]
d = [430, 431, 432,...,463]

list_combined = [(p,q,r,s)   for p in a 
                             for q in b 
                             for r in c 
                             for s in d]

import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('combined.xlsx')

worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

for row, group in enumerate(list_combined):
    for col in range(5):
        worksheet.write (row, col, group[col])
workbook.close()
```

Comment: When you mean "print a list into excel" you mean to _write_ the data into an excel file, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python XlsxWriter - Write to many sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522394/python-xlsxwriter-write-to-many-sheets)

Comment: Also you are mentioning 4 lists that you do not use, and then make refernce to variables called `list1` and so without showing their definition. Are you not missing sth out there?

Comment: Please, just look: https://www.google.com/search?q=xlswriter+python+write+multiple+sheets

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde I wish to print the result derived in list_combined on to excel.

Comment: I think either my answer or the other user's have already tackled such problem

Comment: We are telling you how to print into multiple sheets. How you divide your data is a decision you have to make by thinking, not a problem we have to solve. SO is for particular programming issues.

Comment: You asked: how to dump data into multiple sheets (same file); we answered. Now, the data you save and how you save it depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

First, Python calls need to place the parenthesis just after the name. Spaces are not allowed:

<s>`worksheet.write (row, col, group[col])`</s>
`worksheet.write(row, col, group[col])`

Second, to write into multiple sheets, you need to do as follows:
*Example taken from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38052004/4396006)*

> ```
> import xlsxwriter
> list_name = ["first sheet", "second sheet", "third sheet"]
>
> workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(<Your full path>)
> for sheet_name in list_name:
>     worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(sheet_name)
>     worksheet.write('A1', sheet_name)
>
> workbook.close()
> ```

If you do not want to pass any name to the sheet, remove the `sheet_name` argument, and a default name will be given.

To split data into sheets you can easily adapt the code into:

```
for piece in iterable_data_set:
    # consider "piece" a piece of data you want to put into each sheet
    # `piece` must be an nxm matrix that contains dumpable data.
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    for i in range(len(piece)):
        for j in range(len(piece[i])):
            worksheet.write(i, j, piece[i][j])
```

I recommend you first look for the answer to your question to avoid *duplicate answers*. If once looking for them none solve your problem, then you can go and ask it, also telling how your problem is **different** from others found in other questions.

Answer (score 0):

You could set an upper limit and switch to a new worksheet once you get to the limit.

Here is an example with a lower limit than the limit supported by Excel for testing:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Simulate a big list
biglist = range(1, 1001)

# Set max_row to your required limit. Zero indexed.
max_row = 100
row_num = 0

for data in biglist:

    # If we hit the upper limit then create and switch to a new worksheet
    # and reset the row counter.
    if row_num == max_row:
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
        row_num = 0

    worksheet.write(row_num, 0, data)
    row_num += 1

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Was looking to get the product of the lists in excel.

Comment: You asked “How should I continue printing in the next sheet in the same workbook?”  The example shows how. Just replace `biglist` with your list and `max_row` with the Excel max -1.