# How to write to an excel with multiple worksheets using "xlsxwriter" and not "openpyxl"?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, excel-writer-xlsx

I am looking to store some texts into an `excel` with multiple work-sheets. I tried to do it using `openpyxl` and I am able to achieve it but I am not able to do the same using `xlsxwriter`.

I cannot use `openpyxl`  due to an `IllegalCharacterException` popping up when using it. I know ways to remove or escape these characters but I do not want to remove or escape these characters and want to store them as it is in my `excel`.

I can achieve the maintainence of characters using `xlsxwriter` but not able to store it in multiple worksheets. 
Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python XlsxWriter - Write to many sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522394/python-xlsxwriter-write-to-many-sheets)

Comment: I have a unique data-frame for each excel work-sheet. How do I inculcate it into this?

Comment: @M Nikesh Could you please share some code, and the desired ouput ?

Comment: I will you the pseudo code  --       1.  for loop  which generates a dataframe for each iteration. each dataframe needs to be stored in  a different excel worksheet.

Comment: If you are looking to add data or worksheets to an existing xlsx file then you can't do that with XlsxWriter. What are the characters that cause the `IllegalCharacterException` error? It seems odd that XlsxWriter can handle them and OpenPyXL can't.

Comment: I am trying to create an excel with multiple worksheets using "xlsxwriter"

Comment: for i in range(list1):

Comment: Ok. In that case that is possible. You just need to do multiple calls to `add_worksheet()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```py
import pandas as pd

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("my_results.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")

for i, element in enumerate(elements):
   df = pd.DataFrame(element)
   df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f"element_{i}")
writer.save()
```